# How does the veteran identify this woman as Spanish?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-alienist, the-alienist-angel-of-darkness

In the first episode of ***The Alienist: Angel of Darkness***, a Spanish mother goes to a public park with her baby in a cart. Then a veteran comes over and asks (beggs) for money, when he is turned down, he says: Spanish whxxe.

Here is a screen shot of the way she dresses. [image]

As the background of this TV show is set almost 100 years ago, I am not really sure if her dress gives her away or her looks. I would say the USA has been a country of immigrants from its very beginning, there has to be second generation of third generation of Spanish immigrants living in that era in New York. How could this veteran instantly and accurately identify this woman as a Spanish woman?

Comment: Should there be a tag for "the-alienist-angel-of-darkness"? Or is "the-alienist" sufficient?

Comment: @BCdotWEB, the-alienist would suffice